# Slide Library will not copy slide to presentation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, slidelibrary

I know microsoft has deprecated slide library functionality but my work is still obsessed with it so they keep asking me for help with it. We are using Sharepoint 2013 and we have a workaround for creating slide libraries since it is not easily available in the options.  Our IT Department has been unable to solve this issue but for some people they can copy their slides to a presentation just fine.  Me and several others though, cannot.  I check the boxes of the slides I would like to add to a presentation and then click the magic button and all it does is refresh the page.  My laptop was recently reimaged so maybe some sort of update to IE or Office is the issue. When I press F-12 for the developer console in IE 11 and then try to copy slide to presentation I get the following error in the `sldlib.js`:

`'CallInsertSlides' is undefined`

It is trying to call the function `CallInsertSlides(selItems, objx);`

This function that it is saying is undefined is located on line 775 of the webpage `AllItems.aspx`

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?  If not does anyone know of a program or have a script that can combine single slide powerpoint files into one powerpoint if I have them all in order in the directory?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F12. Go to Emulator. Change the "document mode" to 8.
let the page reload. open with PPT.

You're Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It will not open if you see the 20% sign in the URL.  You will have to create a slide library without the 20% sign..tighten up your URL and it will copy to presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not sure how to fix the slide library's in SharePoint for you, however giving the re-use slides feature in PowerPoint a try it might be a better alternative that is supported for your users.

Here is where Microsoft talks about this slide library feature: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Slide-Libraries-to-share-and-reuse-PowerPoint-slides-C419E77F-8A94-4FC1-A7F0-F5E6CDD7E419#OfficeVersion=Newer_versions

Here is another page from the one above that talks about a re-useing slides in PowerPoint
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/reuse-import-slides-from-another-presentation-c67671cd-386b-45dd-a1b4-1e656458bb86